# ¿Cómo insertar múltiples datos a la base de datos?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mvc

tengo mi aplicación en php con el patrón de diseño modelo vista controlador pero no sé como hacer una inserción multiple de varios datos.

Al añadir una única materia si se guarda en la base de datos pero cuando selecciono algunas materias ya no me guarda. Ayuda por favor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**VISTA**

Esta es la parte visual la cual sale en la imagen donde se muestra el profesor y todas las materias de la base de datos:

```
<label for="agregarAsignacionMateria">Nombre de la Materia</label>
                                    <select multiple="multiple"
                                            class="multiselect-dropdown form-control"
                                            id="agregarAsignacionMateria"
                                            name="agregarAsignacionMateria">
                                        <?php

                                            $item = null;
                                            $valor = null;

                                            $materias = ControladorAsignatura::ctrMostrarAsignatura($item, $valor);

                                            foreach ($materias as $key => $value) {

                                                echo '<option value="' . $value['ID_Asignatura'] . '">' . $value['Nombre_Asignatura'] . '</option>';

                                            }
                                        ?>
                                    </select>
```

**Controlador**

Aquí hago el llamado del name del input para posteriormente enviarselo al modelo y que ejecute la sentencia respectiva:

```
public static function ctrCrearAsignacionMateria()
    {

        if (isset($_POST['agregarAsignacionMateriaDocente'])) {

            $tabla = 'asignatura_docente';
            $datos = array('asignatura' => $_POST['agregarAsignacionMateria'],
                           'docente'    => $_POST['agregarAsignacionMateriaDocente']);

            $respuesta = ModeloAsignacionMateria::mdlCrearAsignacionMateria($tabla, $datos);

            if ($respuesta == 'ok') {

                echo "<script>
                    Swal.fire({
                        type: 'success',
                        title: 'La materia ha sido creada correctamente',
                        confirmButtonText: 'Cerrar',
                        confirmButtonColor: '#3F6AD8',
                        allowOutsideClick: false,
                        allowEscapeKey: false
                    }).then((result)=>{
                        if (result.value){
                            window.location = 'asignacion_materias';
                        }
                    });
                </script>";

            } else {
                echo "<script>
                    Swal.fire({
                        type: 'error',
                        title: 'Error en la base de datos, vuelva a intentarlo en un momento',
                        confirmButtonText: 'Cerrar',
                        confirmButtonColor: '#3F6AD8',
                        allowOutsideClick: false,
                        allowEscapeKey: false
                    }).then((result)=>{
                        if (result.value){
                            window.location = 'asignacion_materias';
                        }
                    });
                </script>";
            }


        }

    }
```

**Modelo**

Aquí en teoría creo la sentencia sql pero si en el input selecciono una única materia si se guarda pero al seleccionar mas materias no se guarda.

```
public static function mdlCrearAsignacionMateria($tabla, $datos)
    {

        $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla (ID_Asignatura, ID_Docente) VALUES (:asignatura, :docente)");

        $stmt->bindParam(':asignatura', $datos['asignatura'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
        $stmt->bindParam(':docente', $datos['docente'], PDO::PARAM_INT);

        if ($stmt->execute()) {

            return 'ok';

        }

        return 'error';

    }
```

**BASE DE DATOS**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola no estoy muy seguro de como estas enviando tus datos de la vista al controlador ya que no pones el form completo pero imagino que debe ser que en tu modelo solo estas ejectando un insert por lo que cuando solo seleccionas una asignatura la inserta, pero son varias ya es array y el valor del parametro :asignatura es un array y tu insert espera un numero por lo cual no debe lanzar una excepcion, lo que debes hacer es recorrer ese array y ejecutar tantos insert segun las asignaturas. mas o menos de la siguiente manera

```
  public static function mdlCrearAsignacionMateria($tabla, $datos)
        {
            $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("INSERT INTO $tabla (ID_Asignatura, ID_Docente) VALUES (:asignatura, :docente)");

            $stmt->bindParam(':docente', $datos['docente'], PDO::PARAM_INT);

            foreach($datos['asignatura'] as $key=>$value){
               $stmt->bindParam(':asignatura', $value, PDO::PARAM_INT);

                if(!$stmt->execute()){
                   return 'error';
                }
             }

            return 'ok';

        }
```

Depende de la forma en que estes enviando tus datos ya que segun eso la estructura de $datos['asignatura'] puede varian en este caso se considera que es un array de enteros.

Por otro lado te recomiendo usar transacciones.

Espero sea lo que estes buscando sino me puedes escribir para ayudarte a resolver tus dudas.

, saludos.

Comment: Excelente solucion compa me funciono mucho, espero puedas ver este mensaje ya que tengo una consultita mas que quiero hacerte pero no se como contactarte

Comment: Hola me alega que te haya sido útil, me puedes hacer la consulta que necesites en el hilo de estos comentarios. o si prefieres por otro medio me dices cual y seguimos en contacto.

Comment: Por el medio en el que pueda contactarte mas seguido o en el cual puedas tengas mas disponibilidad para leer o responder, talvez whatsapp